# RegEx: Find pattern but exclude words

Tags: regex

I want to find all connected words except for specific ones. For example:

> 0827banana82/+wine22green-729

`green` and `wine` should match, but `banana` not.

I tried the following regular expression with a negative lookahead:

> (?!banana)([a-zA-Z]+)

but it excludes only the first letter of `banana` because `anana` is still a match for the second pattern. I have no idea how to get rid of that.

Answer (score 3):

You may add a negative lookbehind in your regex to make it work:

```
(?!banana)(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgV1zG/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!banana)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have string `banana` ahead of the current position
- `(?<![a-zA-Z])`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have a letter before current position
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match 1+ letters

PS: If you want to allow words like `bananas` then use:

```
(?!banana(?![a-zA-Z]))(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use this one:

```
(banana)|([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Which will capture banana in 1st group and all the other words in 2nd.

Comment: You can also use a single capture group `banana|([a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: Note that this will negate a word like "bananas". +

Answer (score 2):

My two cents, assuming you **do** want to match words like "bananas":

```
(\b|\d)(?:banana|([a-zA-Z]+))(?1)
```

Your matches are in group 2, see an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ieDzqs/1)

- `(\b|\d)` - A 1st capture group to hold a word-boundary or a digit.
- `(?:banana|([a-zA-Z]+))` - A non-capture group with the alternation of either exactly "banana" **or** a 2nd capture group of 1+ alpha-chars.
- `(?1)` - Repeat the subpattern of the 1st capture group.

---

***EDIT:*** If the backreference is not supported, you can try

```
(?:\b|\d)(?:banana|([a-zA-Z]+))(?:\b|\d)
```

Or, using lookarounds:

```
(?i)(?<![a-z])(?:banana|([a-z]+))(?![a-z])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation might be matching the characters a-zA-Z until there are no more. Then assert that banana is not directly to the left.

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?![a-zA-Z])(?<!banana)
```

The pattern matches

- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` Negative lookahead, assert not a-zA-Z directly to the right
- `(?<!banana)` Negative lookbehind, assert `banana` not directly to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DSZucr/1)

---

If you want to match `bananas` or `straigtbanana` you can assert that on the left is not banana preceded by a char a-zA-Z

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?![a-zA-Z])(?<!(?<![a-zA-Z])banana)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGRvWY/1)

---

As suggested by @[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)
 in the comments, if [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) are supported and shortening the pattern using a case insensitive match:

```
[a-z]++(?<!(?<![a-z])banana)
```

- `[a-z]++` Match 1+ chars in the range of a-z (possessive, do not backtrack)
- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is not

  - `(?<![a-z])banana` Negative lookbehind, match banana not preceded by a-z
- `)`  Close lookbedhind

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR07t1/1)

Comment: @JvdV Ah I see, I think the second pattern prevents that.

Comment: I like this and was inspired by your pattern 4th Bird to think of a possessive quantifier, if those are supported by the OPs regex flavor: `/[a-z]++(?<!(?<![a-z])banana)/i`.

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes nice! You can post it it you want.

Comment: I'm not in the mood of post new answer these days, maybe next year :p However reading here and there what's happening on the platform.

Comment: @bobblebubble You have really posted some true gems, hope to read some more :-) Is it ok if I add it to the answer?

Comment: Thank you 4th Bird, thats's really appreciated and same to you :) Yes if you like, I'd be happy if you included it.

Comment: @JvdV It can match banana by itself that way right? https://regex101.com/r/OReEX4/1

Comment: I think so yeah. That proves my point wrong haha. Discard it then

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to avoid one single word.

```
(?![banana])([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Comment: Using `[banana]` does not do what you think that is does. It is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching one of the listed characters and is the same as `[bna]`

Answer (score 0):

```txt
/\b(((?!banana|apple|[^\p{L}]).)+)\b/gu
```

You need to use the word boundary `\b` expression `\b`. Banana apple will be excluded from your match.

At the end use `gui` if you want to exclude Banana and Apple too (capitalized text including upper case).

`\p{L}` will match any word including diacritics.

If you need just banana to be excluded delete `|apple`. If you need to add more like orange after apple add `|orange`.

Comment: you have your regex here [link](https://doregex.com/?urlconstruction=WyJ3aWxkIG5leHQgdHJ1ZSAwIiwiMTMiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCJiYW5hbmEiLCJhcHBsZSIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsImZhbHNlIiwiZmFsc2UiLCIvYi9yL2UvYS9rLyIsImRpc2FibGVkIG5leHQgZmFsc2UgMCIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsImZhbHNlIiwiZmFsc2UiLCIvYi9yL2UvYS9rLyIsImRpc2FibGVkIG5leHQgZmFsc2UgMCIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsImZhbHNlIiwiZmFsc2UiLCIvYi9yL2UvYS9rLyIsInRydWUiLCJmYWxzZSIsImZhbHNlIiwidHJ1ZSIsImZhbHNlIiwidHJ1ZSIsImZhbHNlIl0=#crumbstart)